# in javascript what is a sandbox? how do i make one? how do i use it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sandbox

I have an assignment to create a sandbox to explore jQuery. I missed class that day and my web design book literally says nothing about it. I have tried to look it up and I sort of understand it tests the code or something, but really don't see a solid explanation on what it is or how to make one.  keep in mind I am completely new with JavaScript and jQuery, so simplified answers would be appreciated. What is a sandbox? How do I implement one in jQuery? (I am just adding useless text at this point because stack exchange refuses to let me post for some odd reason I am assuming that it is because the description is too short).

Answer (score -1):

There isn't a canonical definition of the word 'sandbox' in this context which is why you couldn't find one by searching. In this case a sandbox probably means setting up a local webserver on your laptop/desktop so you can start playing with building your own sites; plenty of tutorials on this process exist. It can also in the context of javascript refer to the mediator/facade pattern in the three-tier architecture popularized by Nicholas Zakas.